# How to pass body in post request fetch api call in React Native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

My url if opened on browser gives the following error:(attached image)

[image]
Body of my api call looks like below :

```
{
      "entityId": 4071,
      "listViewId": 0,
      "asLookup": false,
      "retrieveAllFields": true,
      "fullTextSearch": "",
      "query": [

      ],
      "pagination": {
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "recordsCountPerPage": 0
      },
      "sorting": {
        "fieldId": 0,
        "direction": 0
      }
    }
```

I am calling api in react native using fetch below :

```
 try {
            let response = await fetch('url', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'tenantid': '1',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'language': '0',

                },
                body: JSON.stringify({

                    entityId: 4071,
                    listViewId: 0,
                    asLookup: false,
                    retrieveAllFields: true,
                    fullTextSearch: "",
                    query: [

                    ],
                    pagination: {
                        pageNumber: 0,
                        recordsCountPerPage: 0
                    },
                    sorting: {
                        fieldId: 0,
                        direction: 0
                    }

                })
            })
      let json = await response.json();
      console.log("This is response" + json)
      this.setState({records: json.results, isFetching:false});
    }catch(error){
      this.setState({errorMessage:error})
      console.log("This is error"+error)
    }
```

This gives me response : Network failed request. Also tried with the inverted commas, still same response. I am newbie in react native but I have made api calls in the past but this one wouldnt work. If anyone can look into this, would be of great help!

Answer (score 3):

did you use the correct url ?

it should looks like something like this

```
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
      body: JSON.stringify({
                firstParam: 'yourValue',
                secondParam: 'yourOtherValue'})
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
     });
```

maybe you should look on the documentations
https://reactnative.dev/docs/network